# SQL analytics function window size based on result in window

Tags: sql, hive

I require a criteria for the window size based on the calculation in the window.

For example the calculation in column col_2:

| idx | col_0 | col_1 | col_2 | rows in window |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | A | 10 | 30 | 1,2 |
| 2 | A | 20 | NULL | - |
| 3 | A | 50 | 50 | 3 |
| 4 | B | 10 | 50 | 4,5,6 |
| 5 | B | 10 | NULL | - |
| 6 | B | 30 | 30 | 6 |

Basically, col_2 means something like sum(col_1) in [30,50] for the window in col_0 based only on the following columns. A query could be like

```
SELECT *, 
SUM(col_1) OVER (PARTITION BY col_0 ROWS BETWEEN CURRENT ROW AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING WHERE SUM(col_1) BETWEEN 30 AND 50) AS col_2
FROM table
```

I didn't find any function or sql snippet which efficiently solves this problem.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: is rows in window part of the table?  otherwise how do we know when col_1 breaks?  wait row 6 is included in two groups?  Yeah No...  there's no pattern.

Comment: The column `rows in window` is just a comment row, ignore it. It states which following rows are cumulated in order to fulfill the requirement that the sum must be in [30,50].

Comment: ok so 6 has values in Col_2 becuase it is both part of the 50 total and the 30 total.

Comment: Still think this is interesting just haven't had time to spend on it.

Comment: A possible solution is the following:
1. Sum col_2 from current to unbounded `SUM(col_2) OVER (PARTITION BY col_0 ROWS BETWEEN CURRENT ROW AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING) AS col_3`
2. Now collect a list from current to unbounded of col_3 `COLLECT_LIST(col_3) OVER (PARTITION BY col_0 ROWS BETWEEN CURRENT ROW AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING) AS col_4`
3. Write a user defined function to subtract value in col_3 from each value in array in col_4 and times -1.
4. Then a second udf for searching the desired value in the calculated array.
It's a bit engineered but it works :)